# is this sql injection error?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, code-injection

i want to know if is this sql injection error or what ?
and what db is there ? mssql ?

**A Database Error Occurred**

```
Error Number: 1054
Unknown column '20and' in 'where clause'
```

**For Query** :-

```
select * from static_info where main_id=60%20and 
and language_code='az' order by id desc
```

**At Location** :-

```
Filename: /home/test/public_html/controllers/welcome.php
Line Number: 115
```

Comment: The link you provided in comments below, and the error message that comes up is a sign of poorly written code, and often in PHP applications poorly written database code is vulnerable to injection attacks. But there is no way to say based solely on what's provided here. Read up on PDO (as suggested by others below) and edit the question to include the relevant parts of welcome.php. At that point people might be better able to assist you.

Comment: To answer your question, yes it does look like sql injection. The answer on the DB you should know.

Comment: What was your input?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use single quotes for character columns

```
select * from static_info where main_id='60%20and' and language_code='az' 
order by id desc
```

Comment: and it means there is no sql injection warning?

Comment: ratherç i want to know if this sql injection ?

Comment: It is not a SQL Injection warning. It is the error about invalid column names. However you can use a stored procedure with parameters and execute it using sp_executesql to avoid sql injection

Comment: no, @lenonCon have a sql injection vulnerability. Please use prepared queries. See PDO in the php docs.

Comment: and  http://nidavh.org/news_index/60%20and  please see here how to do sql injection ??

Comment: check out whether Error Number: 1054 is part of sql injection or not..?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be said as sql injection,because user can access your database from UTL, User can easily execute queries in database and harm to your database, If you notice     [link]http://nidavh.org/news_index/1 , 
this will execute as a "select * from static_info where main_id=1 ..." and i can see staic pages by id.  I hope you got my point

You should use parameterized query to prevent sql injections

```
 Select * from TableName where Columnname1='Your Paremeters' and Columnname2='Your Parameters'
```

Comment: http://nidavh.org/news_index/60%20and  please see here how to do sql injection ??

Answer (score 0):

They are using Codeigniter for the framework,

the error which you posted is just telling you there's no `20and` field existed,

it's just an `404 Not Found` like error, and the symbol which you trying to use will be **escape**,

that's one way to prevent SQL injection, there's a lot also.

And if you trying to SQL injection then you'll get the following error:

```
An Error Was Encountered

The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.
```